# Rails5 and Devise: Login form for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models: **user** and **employee_user**, how can I setup a login form to authenticate two models at the same time? I need to login form check in what model he needs to authentiate the user

**ApplicationHelper**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

**Form**

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>

      <%= f.email_field :email, required: true, placeholder: "Email" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: :off, required: true, placeholder: "Password" %>

      <%= f.submit 'ENTER', class: "btLogin" %>

      <div class="infosLembrar">
        <p><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember me</p>
      </div>

    <% end %>
```

Someone already did it before? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have two user types? That sounds like a giant hassle compared to a single model with a `role` flag that could be set to `"employee"`.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the question and it it's not an answer.

Comment: Just trying to establish if this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) or not. If you have two different models you probably need two different forms, or the one form has to try against both authentication methods in turn using a custom session controller.

Answer (score 0):

Devise has a wiki on this. Please check: [How to Setup Multiple Devise User Models](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models)

Hope this helps!